# Can you use Psionic Mastery twice to stack up more points before spending them?

Tags: dnd-5e, psionics, unearthed-arcana

In later levels of the [UA Mystic](http://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/UAMystic3.pdf) they are able to their Psionic Mastery Feature multiple times. So they get one use of it at 9th level and two uses at 13th level.

Is one able to use the Feature, not use the Special Psi Points given, then use the feature again stacking the Special Points given by it?

Answer (score 3):

### The UA rules don't say that you can't

This is play test level material, not polished, as WoTC warns on page 1.

As written, you keep those bonus points until you finish a long rest. (p. 5)  The language, as written, does not indicate a flush/loss of points if you activate a second instance of this special feature.  You only lose them if you have not expended them before you finish a long rest.

> When you finish a long rest, you lose any of these special points that
>   you haven’t spent.

An alternative interpretation of the text (such as it is) would be that each usage of this feature creates a separate "points pool" ... so that, for example, if you opened both instances in consecutive turns, you'd have two pools of 9 points rather than one pool of 18 points.  This could (mechanically) limit your chance to, for example, stack three effects that each cost six points. (Since your  pools would for that purpose be (6+3) and (6+3))  That kind of detail is not in the test material as presented.  (Thanks to @DaleM).

#### Recommendation

If you are playing a UA mystic, I suggest you work with your DM/other players and try this out and see how it influences play.  After you've gotten a feel for it, provide WoTC feedback via their web site ([Unearthed Arcana, which is under *Articles*](http://dnd.wizards.com/articles/unearthed-arcana)) to let them know how it worked at your table.

This is the third attempt at psionics/The Mystic so far for D&D 5e.  UA is billed as play test material, so I'd recommend using it in that spirit.

Comment: Thank you.My current DM and I have been talking about how ridiculous/silly the Mystics can get with how they can spend their points

Comment: @Twiggy Feel free to upvote the answer, if it is helpful, and if you'd like you can accept it, or (probably a better option) wait for another answer to come along that  might be better before choosing one to accept.

Comment: An alternative interpretation might be that each usage creates a separate "points pool"

Comment: @DaleM Yeah, I'll add that.  Good point.